# How to register Geofence after device restarted?

Tags: android, gps, android-geofence

I built an app that popup Notification in location i set.
Everything works smoothly. Even after I Rebooting my device. There is no problem. But I noticed that if I turn off the GPS and then reboot my device the BroadcastReceiver probably trying to login the Geofence api and gets error because there is no GPS. and the Geofence notification are not popup any more, till i reboot my device with gps on mode.
Will I have to use AlarmManager? For push some refresh every x time? To verify that a GPS mode is on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution is assuming you are already storing the geofence information you want to use in a manner that will persist through reboots of the device.

On first start, in the BroadcastReceiver that handles the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`, do a check to see if GPS [is enabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isProviderEnabled(java.lang.String)).  If it is, continue normally, but if not, add this to your receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //Or whatever action your receiver accepts
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER){
            context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));
        }
        else{
            //We are good, continue with adding geofences!
        }
    }

    if(intent.getAction().equals(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)){
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER){
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            //We got our GPS stuff up, add our geofences!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's Works ! Thank you very much

Comment: Do i have to use :" context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)); Or mContext.unregisterReceiver(this) ?

Comment: You should be find just unregistering using the 'context' variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your manifest. This example assumes you have a BroadcastReceiver com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver, replace that with your own. This receiver will get broadcast intents whenever the GPS turns on or off.

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```